# How to clear the WYSIWYG mathquill editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, mathquill

At this address: http://jenseng.github.io/mathquill/demo.html

I open a web console and type:

```
$(document.getElementsByClassName("mathquill-editor")).mathquill('latex','')
```

It successfully clears the WYSIWYG editor at the bottom of the page, but then I can't type anything else in. It also moves the cursor from the left side to the right side. Any ideas how to make the text box editable and move the cursor to the left again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to happen because when you run `.mathquill('latex', info)`, it also removes the necessary elements to use the editor.  The editor (`$('.mathquill-editor')`) needs its first 2 children to be able to function, the rest are part of mathquill.

The main way to clear it is the following:

```
while ($('.mathquill-editor').children().length > 2)
    $('.mathquill-editor').children()[2].remove();
$('.mathquill-editor').addClass('empty');
```

But I will also include a more dynamic way, in case the above code doesn't work on another website and/or the classname isn't the same.

### JQuery

```
function clearEditor(elem) {
    while ($(elem).children().length > 2)
        $(elem).children()[2].remove();
    $(elem).addClass('empty');
}
clearEditor('.mathquill-editor');
```

### Pure Javascript

```
function clearEditor(elem) {
    while (document.querySelector(elem).children.length > 2)
        document.querySelector(elem).children[2].remove();
    document.querySelector(elem).setAttribute('class', document.querySelector(elem).getAttribute('class') + ' empty');
}
clearEditor('.mathquill-editor');
```

Comment: This will cause the text area of the editor to be a little small, and you have to click in a certain spot to be able to edit again.

Comment: Thanks this is the majority of the answer! Now if we can just get the "little small...certain spot" figured out

Comment: I edited the answer to add a class of "empty" which is used to fix the size, so now it works.

Comment: @SethKitchen : if this is the answer , I think you should give the bounty to  Jaketr00 . Anyways this 50 bounty is not refundable to you . :)

Comment: @YoYo he answered too quickly i was unable to give bounty. Now given :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can tell which keystrokes you want the editor to perform.

mathquillEditor.focus();

mathquillEditor.keystroke('End Shift-Home Del');